# Since when does peer-reviewed editing exist?

Tags: discussion

I just edited a question and saw the message saying *“You do not have edit privileges. Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.”*. This, in turn, raises two questions and a comment:

- It seems to me that it is new, so: Since when does that exist?
- Does one need to reach a certain reputation to propose peer-reviewed edits?
- **It rocks! Thanks guys** for adding this in addition to “normal” edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite new indeed, see the meta Meta:

- [Allow low-rep users to suggest edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74447/allow-low-rep-users-to-suggest-edits) (9 January, tagged [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) as of right now)
- [Diff is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75377/diff-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) (18 January)
- [Is everyone in favor of the new “everyone can edit” idea?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75581/is-everyone-in-favor-of-the-new-everyone-can-edit-idea-is-this-really-such-a-g) (19 January)
- [How does peer review for edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work) (24 January)

From the latter, quoting waffles:

> As it stands (and this is *all subject to change* until the feature is formally announced):
>
> #### Who can suggest an edit?
>
> - Users with 2k rep can make edits at will without needing to "suggest" them of, course!
> - Registered users can suggest an edit to any post
> - Anonymous users can suggest edits to any post *more than 1 day old*
>
> #### Where do suggested edits go?
>
> Suggested edits are held in a peer review queue of a fixed size. If the queue fills up, no more edit suggestions will be allowed until the queue has some empty space.
>
> #### How do suggested edits get approved?
>
> Our goal is
>
> 1. Have two reviewers look at each edit in the ideal case to ensure quality of edit.
> 2. Ensure that many reviewers are participating in the process and all edits are not being approved or rejected by a single reviewer.

Again, this is all subject to change. Wait for the official announcement on the [blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/).

---

**Edit 7 Feb 2011:** et voilà, [Suggested Edits and Edit Review](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/).

Comment: Thanks RegDwight for the info, it's indeed quite recent!